# mongodb aggregation framework $match - $lookup - $project (failing to use $project for structuring the result)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Sample Data:

users collection:

```
[
    {
        "_id":ObjectId("614804bb4236d9b0896f4e7c"),
        "firstName":"Fabian",
        "lastName":"Barlow"
    },
    {
        "_id":ObjectId("614804bb4236d9b0896f4e7d"),
        "firstName":"Chloe",
        "lastName":"Mendez"
    },
    {
        "_id":ObjectId("614804bb4236d9b0896f4e7e"),
        "firstName":"Valentine",
        "lastName":"Sharp"
    }
]
```

bookings collection:

```
[
    {
        "_id":ObjectId("614805534236d9b0896f4e86"),
        "resourceName":"res-1",
        "duration":"10 days",
        "status":"active",
        "bookingCreatorId":ObjectId("614804bb4236d9b0896f4e7c")
    },
    {
        "_id":ObjectId("614805534236d9b0896f4e87"),
        "resourceName":"res-2",
        "duration":"15 days",
        "status":"active",
        "bookingCreatorId":ObjectId("614804bb4236d9b0896f4e7d")
    },
    {
        "_id":ObjectId("614805534236d9b0896f4e88"),
        "resourceName":"res-3",
        "duration":"15 days",
        "status":"completed",
        "bookingCreatorId":ObjectId("614804bb4236d9b0896f4e7d")
    }
]
```

I am trying to perform an aggregation query on the above collection "bookings", to get the result in a particular structure,
While using project i am trying to add a new field "bookingCreatorDetails" which needs to hold data from "users" collections, but instead of getting the correct data for users collections, i am  getting "Array" type for the fields inside "bookingCreatorDetails"

Attempt on creating the query ("bookings"):

```
[
    {
        '$match': {
        'status': 'active'
        }
    }, {
        '$lookup': {
        'from': 'users', 
        'localField': 'bookingCreatorId', 
        'foreignField': '_id', 
        'as': 'bookingCreator'
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
        'resourceName': 1, 
        'duration': 1, 
        'bookingCreatorId': 1, 
        'bookingCreatorDetails.firstName': '$bookingCreator.firstName', 
        'bookingCreatorDetails.lastName': '$bookingCreator.lastName'
        }
    }
]
```

Current incorrect result:

```
[
    {
        "_id":ObjectId("614805534236d9b0896f4e86"),
        "resourceName":"res-1",
        "duration":"10 days",
        "status":"active",
        "bookingCreatorId":ObjectId("614804bb4236d9b0896f4e7c"),
        "bookingCreatorDetails": {
            "firstName":Array,
            "lastName":Array
        }
    },
    {
        "_id":ObjectId("614805534236d9b0896f4e87"),
        "resourceName":"res-2",
        "duration":"15 days",
        "status":"active",
        "bookingCreatorId":ObjectId("614804bb4236d9b0896f4e7d"),
        "bookingCreatorDetails": {
            "firstName":Array,
            "lastName":Array
        }
    }
]
```

Expected Result:

```
[
    {
        "_id":ObjectId("614805534236d9b0896f4e86"),
        "resourceName":"res-1",
        "duration":"10 days",
        "status":"active",
        "bookingCreatorId":ObjectId("614804bb4236d9b0896f4e7c"),
        "bookingCreatorDetails": {
            "firstName":"Fabian",
            "lastName":"Barlow"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id":ObjectId("614805534236d9b0896f4e87"),
        "resourceName":"res-2",
        "duration":"15 days",
        "status":"active",
        "bookingCreatorId":ObjectId("614804bb4236d9b0896f4e7d"),
        "bookingCreatorDetails": {
            "firstName":"Chloe",
            "lastName":"Mendez"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $lookup will always return in array of objects format, You can use `$arrayElemAt` operator to select first element from the array or `$first` operator from 4.4,

- using `$arrayElemAt` operator

```
  {
    "$project": {
      "resourceName": 1,
      "duration": 1,
      "bookingCreatorId": 1,
      "bookingCreatorDetails": {
        $arrayElemAt: ["$bookingCreator", 0]
      }
    }
  }
```

- using `$first` operator

```
  {
    "$project": {
      "resourceName": 1,
      "duration": 1,
      "bookingCreatorId": 1,
      "bookingCreatorDetails": {
        $first: "$bookingCreator"
      }
    }
  }
```

---

Out of the question if you want to remove `_id` from lookup result you can use `$unset` stage after your `$project` stage,

```
  { $unset: "bookingCreatorDetails._id" }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i was doing one more mistake, i was saving "bookingCreatorId" as string where as it should be ObjectId, because its compared with "users._id" during the lookup which is of ObjectId type, i have updated my question to correct types for ids